# R for loops: when to use i in seq_along(x) and when to use i in x

Tags: r, for-loop

I am very new to R and got stuck on writing for loops. Sometime I see people write: `for (i in seq_along(x))`, while other times they write `for (i in x)`. What is the difference between the two? Does it depend on the properties of x? Help appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following vector `x`:

```
x <- LETTERS[1:5]
x
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E"
```

If you perform a `for` loop on `x` you are using the values of `x`:

```
for(i in x) print(i)
[1] "A"
[1] "B"
[1] "C"
[1] "D"
[1] "E"
```

If instead you use `seq_along`, you are creating an integer sequence of the same length as `x`:

```
for(i in seq_along(x)) print(i)
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 3
[1] 4
[1] 5
```

Which one is appropriate for which situation is dependent on what you're ultimately trying to do. However, I frequently find myself using `seq_along` because it is trivial to subset `x` with `i`, but finding the index of `x` of `i` is more typing.

```
for(i in seq_along(x)) print(x[i])
[1] "A"
[1] "B"
[1] "C"
[1] "D"
[1] "E"
```

Another approach you sometimes might see is using `1:length(x)`. However, as @GregorThomas points out, this can cause unexpected behavior.

Consider the following empty vector `y`:

```
y <- vector()
for(i in seq_along(y)) print(1+i)
```

This results in no output because `seq_along(y)` evaluates to a zero-length vector.

In contrast, consider `1:length(y)`:

```
for(i in 1:length(y)) print(1+i)
[1] 2
[1] 1
```

This is because `1:length(y)` evaluates to `c(1,0)`.

Comment: Perhaps worth adding `1:length(x)` to the comparison, with a 0-length example to show why `seq_along(x)` can be safer than than `1:length(x)`.